# How to pass JavaScript list of directory variables to Python Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, post

I want to pass a list of dictionary from JavaScript+HTML to Python+Flask and use it as a list of dictionary.

Here is my JavaScript:

```
List = [];


    function AddN(x, y, List, Field,selected = false) {
            List.push({
                id: ID,
                x: x,
                y: y,
                neighbour: [ID],
                selected: selected
            });
            ID += 1;
            document.getElementById(Field).value=List;
        }
```

And later I have a hidden input in the HTML form for POSTing the list.

And my Python goes like this:

```
    @app.route("/Input.html",methods=["GET","POST"])
    def input():
        if request.method == "POST":
           nA = request.values.getlist("ListA")
```

Where ListA is the ID and the name of the mentioned hidden input in HTML form.
By using print() I can see my Python is getting a type:list variable, but it is empty and I am sure it is not empty in the HTML+JS.

Any idea?

Thank you.
————————————————————————————————————————————————
Edit:

Here is the code I used to post in my HTML:

```
<form>
..........
<input type="hidden" id="ListA">
<input type="submit" id="Submit">
</form>
```

And I've tried this too(not used together with the input-hidden method):

```
$.ajax({
    url:"/InputCanvas.html",
    type:"POST",
    data:JSON.stringify(answer)
});
```

The other variables(floats and integers) are passed to the Python correctly. Only the lists are empty.

---

Edit:

I've changed the HTML tag and added a name to it. The program is posting some list of string which looks like this: ["[object Object],[object Object]"] and always with length 1.

Comment: How are you posting the list in the javascript? Can you share the code?

Comment: Thank you. I had added my posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks your `input` html element is missing the `name` attribute, so the form sent to the server is missing `ListA`. Change it to:

```
<input type="hidden" id="ListA" name="ListA">
```

---

In order to load the list in your Flask I would make the following changes:

1. set the value of the `input` element to a properly formatted json string in your function `AddN`. Make sure you enclose property names in *double quotes* (otherwise the `json.loads` won't parse the json correctly):

   `var value = {"list": List }
    document.getElementById(Field).value=JSON.stringify(value);`
2. change the Python to parse the string as json:

   `listA = request.values.get("ListA")
    value = json.loads(listA)`

Then you can access you list using `value['list']`.

Comment: Thank you. It is passing now but as strings.

Comment: @NinaZ yeah, you have to parse it into a dict using e.g. `json.loads`. HTTP can only send textual data.

Comment: @JaredSmith If I use JSON.parse() in my hidden input, some of the other JS functions will be broken. I have no idea why because this input should be used for passing variables only.

Comment: Did I say anything about `JSON.parse`? `json.loads` is a *Python* function.

Comment: @JaredSmith If the string looks like "[a:1,b:2]" I can use json.loads in Python, but now it looks like object Object.

Comment: Thank you. I've fixed it using JSON.stringify and json.loads

Comment: @NinaZ Glad to hear that.